# How register JavaFX class in kryonet?

Tags: java, javafx, kryonet

I need some help with the Kryonet lib.
I create a server, with a network class for registering my classes.
But I work with JavaFX and i can't register all of class I need...

Ex this work :

```
kryo.register(ArrayList.class);
kryo.register(ImageView.class);
```

But in Kryonet when I would like to send an ImageView, Kryo need I register all of ImageView's property like Node Orientation. And i can't do that because i got this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: javafx.scene.Node$EffectiveOrientationProperty
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(javafx.scene.Node$EffectiveOrientationProperty.class);
```

but Node$EffectiveOrientationProperty is not a class. And just register Node.class is not enough for Kryo.

Somebody for helping me please?

Thank you. I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: it isnt possible to create rendered images (`ImageView`), transfer the renders and expect them to be compatible on the receiving end - that doesnt make any sense since java objects are bound to your local VM and in your case `ImageView` is also bound to your local JFX context and rendering pipeline - these are images for **your** environment, they wont work anywhere else. If you want to transfer images you need to send and receive the files themselves -- their byte-array content, to be precise.

Comment: I understand (I think :p) but in my app i need to send an ArrayList<ImageView> by the server to all TCP. Because I need to all of clients have the same list.

Comment: Yet again : thats impossible. You cannot have two **identical** lists on different machines - thats not how computers _(or the JVM, for that matter)_ work. You **can** have two lists which contain the same **image data values**, though -- these lists are not identical yet the images will look identical to the human eye (because their data is identical). **You need to transfer lists of byte arrays**.